# Picasso - Download image once then load into multiple ImageView

Tags: android, picasso

Does anyone know how to download an image once then use the same `Picasso` instance to load into multiple `ImageView`? Right now I'm using a (pretty bad) workaround like the one below, in order to be sure the image is already cached and not downloaded again.

```java
Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load(photo.getPath()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_outfit).fit().centerCrop().into(image1, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Picasso.with(container.getContext()).load(photo.getPath()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_outfit).fit().centerCrop().into(image2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: All Picasso will download the image once. It'll cache the image. Just use it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    Picasso.with(container.getContext())
        .load(photo.getPath())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_outfit)
        .fit()
        .centerCrop().into(image1, new Callback() {

          @Override
          public void onSuccess() {
              imageView2.setImageDrawable(image1.getDrawable()); //Get the ImageView's image (this won't download it, it will get the downloaded image) and set it to your second imageView.
          }

          @Override
          public void onError() {

          }
        });
```

To use `centerCrop()`, just add:

```
imageView2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: wouldn't this avoid to use the `Picasso.fit().centerCrop()` automatic resize for `imageView2`?

Comment: @NicolaBeghin if `imageView2` has the same dimensions of `image1`, then yes. Otherwise, no. I'm thinking of another solution :)

Comment: @NicolaBeghin I found a way. Edited my question